# Finding a sensible range

Tags: r

I'm struggling with this now for a few days. This is now the 3rd question at stackoverflow about the same topic, hope this time my question is better defined.

My data are distributed like this: 
(To replicate the data):

```
datag <- data.frame(Probability=rgamma(10000, shape=0.6, rate=4.8, scale=1/4.8))
datag <- subset(datag, Probability<=1)
```

The data represent probabilities: from 0 to 1.

I want to assign states from state 1 to state 10 sensibly to the probability range.

This is what I have got:

```
Interval <- round(quantile(datag, c(seq(0,1,by=0.10))),3)
```

output:

```
  0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
0.000 0.008 0.015 0.024 0.036 0.054 0.080 0.124 0.209 0.397 1.000
```

Assign states from 0 to 10:

```
States <- data.frame(datag, State=findInterval(datag, Interval))
```

head(States)

Output: States

```
Probability      State
0.20585012         8
0.21202839         9
0.07087725         6
0.7109513         10
0.9641807         10
```

The problem is this: As you can see above, I have already state 9 for probability 0.2120 and state 10 for > 0.710. I would be happy with something like prob=0.2120 state 4 and prob=0.710 state 7 and prob=0.96 = state 10.

So how to assign states more uniformly?